# Ext.grid.Panel edits are ignored

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, edit

I have a simple grid panel which needs to support editing. Visually, it seems to work ok but once I try to get all the users in the data store it is as if all edits are ignored.

Here's the code:

```
var myData = 
[        
];

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', 
                        {
                            model: 'User',
                            data: myData
                        });

var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1
});

// create the grid and specify what field you want
// to use for the editor at each header.
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: 
    [
        {
            id: 'email',
            header: 'User email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1,
            field: 
            {
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },           
        {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            header: 'IsManager',
            dataIndex: 'isManager',
            width: 55
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            header: 'IsContractor',
            dataIndex: 'isContractor',
            width: 55
        }
    ],
    selModel: {
        selType: 'cellmodel'
    },        
    frame: false,
     listeners : 
     {
        delay: 1, // time for render
        validateedit: function(editor, e)
        {
            //console.log(e.value);
            //console.log(e.originalValue);
            e.cancel = true;
            e.record.data[e.field] = e.value;
        }
     },
    tbar: 
    [
        {
            text: 'Add User',
            handler : function()
            {
                // Create a record instance through the ModelManager
                var r = Ext.ModelManager.create(
                {
                    email: '',
                    isManager: true,
                    isContractor: false
                }, 
                'User');

                store.insert(store.data.length, r);
                cellEditing.startEditByPosition({row: store.data.length, column: 0});
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Remove selected user',
            handler : function()
            {
                var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();

                if(selection)
                    store.remove(selection); // all selections
            }
        }
    ],
    plugins: [cellEditing]
});
```

I'm using Extjs 4.2

Even calling store.commitChanges() makes no difference. If I don't call it and go through the store I can see records have the dirty flag on but the modified value is the same as the initial value! The weird part is that I can see the value being there if I put a breakpoint in the validateedit function. However, once all editing and adding is done, when I go through store.data.items all rows look the same (= what Ext.ModelManager.create outputs in Add user). I have tried setting autoSave, autoSync and autoLoad to true in the store but it doesn't make any difference.

EDIT:

Here is the user model:

```
Ext.define('User', 
    {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [            
            {name: 'email', type: 'string'},            
            {name: 'isManager', type: 'bool'},
            {name: 'isContractor', type: 'bool'},            
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Where is your `User` model? Does it have the fields that you are editing defined?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to copy paste it. I've added it now.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It works in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pdq): 1. Select ExtJS 4.2.1.883 Netpune, click Run Fiddle and wait for the interface to show up; 2. Click Add User; 3. Double click on the User email field, enter a value, press Enter to finish editing. 4. Click Check and see the record values in the console, including the email value entered. I suggest you post your fiddle to show the problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I press the add button but it throws this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined". I'm using Chrome 43.

Comment: That error happens to me too if I leave ExtJS 5.1 in the Framework select box. The fiddle works in 4.2 only. Did you select 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `e.record.data[e.field] = e.value;` is changing the values in your store, acording to the doc it's just a util object. If you actually want to modify your store, you should use something like this :

```
 validateedit: function(editor, e)
 {
        store.getbyId("Your object Id property").set(e.field, e.value);
 }
```

But your model need an 'Id' or 'IdProperty'

Comment: I don't know how to use store.getById but instead I've used store.getAt(index). Even so, I can't see any difference. For instance, store.getAt(0).data does show the modified data, store.getAt(0).modified shows the modified field but with the old value and store.getAt(0).raw shows the old values. After store.commitChanges() everything is the same except modified = {}.